# Getting id from another table in a relationship laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, one-to-many

I want to get the data from pdf_Files table where it will only show the name of files based on it user_id. I don't really know how to explain it but maybe if you see my codes, you would understand. I have already finish making the relationship between this 2 tables already

I want it to be something like:

```
DB::table('pdf_files')->where(table:personal_infos->id = pdf_files->user_id)->get();  --> I want it to be something like that but I do not know how to get it
```

Here is my code:
Controller:

public function downfunc(Request $request){

```
$downloads=DB::table('pdf_files')->get();
return view('download.viewfile',compact('downloads'));
```

}

pdfFile model:

```
   protected $fillable = array('file_name','file_size','user_id');

public function personal_infos() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\personal_info', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

personal_info model:

```
class personal_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Email', 'Name');
    protected $table = 'personal_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function pdfFiles() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\pdfFile','user_id');
}
```

}

Comment: Do i use some join function or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to search multiple user ids at once or are you getting the id from the request?

If you are getting the info from the request, you would want to do something like this:

```
use App\pdfFile; //Put this above the class

pdfFile::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->get(); //If you are checking to see if something equals something else in eloquent, you do not have to use equals
```

Comment: yes i wanted to do something like that, thanks a lot, but i am getting 0 results return why?? My database, the pdfFile table contain something yet no results is being shown

Comment: First, make sure spelling is correct on everything. Usually in Laravel, the proper formatting for accessing relational tables is to have the id in plural, for example, users_id instead of user_id. Next, try just returning the results. add `return` before pdfFile, my guess is the formatting in the view is incorrect.

Comment: Yup my spelling is correct, i check my models also and when i do a normal return, it return my data

Comment: i tried using dd($download) and it return me this "Collection {#233 ▼
  #items: []
}"

Comment: So, it's returning an empty array, is that correct?

Comment: never mind it ok, maybe i go and ask another question instead, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yup it empty but if i used the DB:table it return my data @EricBrown